# Argument not optional, how can I change it?

Tags: vba, autocad

I'm getting a message  Argument not optional running the code below:

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim linia As AcadLine
Dim Pt1(0 To 2) As Double
Dim stopien(0 To 3) As Double
Dim segment As Variant
Dim n As Double
Dim h As Double

n = CDbl(TextBox1)
h = CDbl(TextBox2)

Pt1(0) = 10# '
Pt1(1) = 10# '
Pt1(2) = 0# '


segment = Pt1

For Licznik = 0 To n - 1

stopien(0) = segment(0)
stopien(1) = segment(1)
stopien(2) = segment(0) + h
stopien(3) = segment(1)

Set linia = ThisDrawing.ModelSpace.AddLine(stopien)

segment(0) = stopien(2)
segment(1) = stopien(3)


Next

End Sub
```

I can debug it , but if I write something in the `TextBox1` or `TextBox2` I get this message.

I don't know how I can fix it

Comment: At what line does the error appear?

Comment: Put some breakpoints in the code to debug it, are you getting the message 'Argument not optional' in the lines `n = Cdbl(TextBox1)`?

Answer (score 2):

The error message is telling you exactly what the issue is... namely, that you are not supplying a needed argument.  In this case, the offending line is below:

```
Set linia = ThisDrawing.ModelSpace.AddLine(stopien)
```

The [AddLine method](https://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2020/ENU/?guid=GUID-26C95029-14BB-40B9-9987-49EFC980CB9D) takes both a StartPoint and an EndPoint, and you are only supplying one of them.

Answer (score 0):

CDbl to the textbox.. hmm.. Shouldn't that be Textbox1.value ? I think you need more uh error handling on the input for Textbox1 and Textbox2.

For example do something like this before you start converting - so put a breakpoint on your first value set of n = CDbl(Textbox1). Then make sure you can see the debug / immediate views in VBA editor. Then write something like this or add Textbox1 to a watch, and expand it's properties to make sure you are using the object's values correctly.

```
Debug.print(Textbox1)
Debug.print(Textbox1.value)
```

To handle problems in conversion or w/e, you want to add error handles to the value checks before you set the values to variables.

> [MrExcel classic discussion on userform handling input errors](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/userform-textbox-error-handling.314914/)